# get the argmax from an array and save it - python

Tags: python, arrays, argmax

I have an array like the one below.  How can I take the argmax from this array and save it as a dataframe.

array

```
([[  4.33578761e-03,   1.11002535e-01,   1.18002132e-01,
      2.23158062e-01,   3.57010156e-01,   9.33912754e-01],
   [  3.21856714e-05,   3.46616306e-03,   4.58798464e-03,
      7.65424687e-03,   1.02789648e-01,   9.99610841e-01]], dtype=float32) was passed
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering n as numpy array

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([[  4.33578761e-03,   1.11002535e-01,   1.18002132e-01,
      2.23158062e-01,   3.57010156e-01,   9.33912754e-01],
   [  3.21856714e-05,   3.46616306e-03,   4.58798464e-03,
      7.65424687e-03,   1.02789648e-01,   9.99610841e-01]], dtype=float)

# printing argmax at axis = 0
print(np.argmax(n, axis=0))
#print(n.argmax(axis=0))
```

---

```
a_max = np.argmax(n, axis=0)
np.save(open("your_file_path", "w"), a_max)
```

and to load

```
a_max = np.load(open("your_file_path"))
```

**References**

- [Numpy argmax documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)
- [Numpy save documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)
- [Numpy load documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)

Comment: can you save the print?

Comment: if you meant saving result of `argmax` in a variable, then yes you can.

Comment: how can you do this? @Wazzzy

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
print (arr.argmax(axis=1))
[5 5]

print (arr.argmax(axis=0))
[0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

First get `argmax` and then use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(arr.argmax(axis=0), columns=['a']))
   a
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  1

print (pd.DataFrame(arr.argmax(axis=0)[None, :]))
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  0  0  1

print (pd.DataFrame(arr.argmax(axis=1), columns=['a']))
   a
0  5
1  5
```

Or create `DataFrame` and call [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
print (pd.DataFrame(arr).idxmax().to_frame('a'))
#same as
#print (pd.DataFrame(arr).idxmax(axis=0).to_frame('a'))
   a
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  1

print (pd.DataFrame(arr).idxmax().to_frame(0).T)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  0  0  1


print (pd.DataFrame(arr).idxmax(axis=1).to_frame('a'))
   a
0  5
1  5
```